How can I reach or read to holes thread description in Catia?
I'm trying to add annotations for every hole about thread description. I achieved adding names or dimensions to all of holes in part. But I wanted to add thread description like m16 etc...
I tried something like this but I got error and all of my annotations in middle of the 0 0 0 pozition. Is this possible writing come close to holes? But main problem is not getting thread descriptions.
Here is what I did in my code:

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // CATIA'yı başlat
                Type catiaType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("CATIA.Application");
                if (catiaType == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("CATIA uygulaması bulunamadı.");
                    return;
                }

                INFITF.Application catiaApp = (INFITF.Application)Activator.CreateInstance(catiaType);
                if (catiaApp == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("CATIA uygulaması başlatılamadı.");
                    return;
                }

                // Açık olan belgeyi al
                Documents documents = catiaApp.Documents;
                if (documents.Count == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Açık belge bulunamadı.");
                    return;
                }

                PartDocument partDoc = (PartDocument)documents.Item(1);
                Part part = partDoc.Part;

                // AnnotationSets ve diğer öğeleri al
                AnnotationSets annotationSets = (AnnotationSets)part.AnnotationSets;
                AnnotationSet annotationSet = annotationSets.Add("ISO_3D");
                Bodies bodies = part.Bodies;
                Body body = bodies.Item("PartBody");
                Shapes shapes = body.Shapes;
                AnnotationFactory annotationFactory = annotationSet.AnnotationFactory;

                int i = 0;

                foreach (Shape shape in shapes)
                {
                    if (shape is Hole hole)
                    {
                        i++;

                        // Deliğin çapını al
                        double diameter = hole.Diameter.Value;

                        // Deliğin metrik tanımını al
                        KnowledgewareTypeLib.StrParam strParam = hole.HoleThreadDescription;
                        string metric = strParam.get_Value();

                        // Kullanıcı yüzeyini oluşturmak için doğrudan Reference kullanma
                        Reference reference = part.CreateReferenceFromObject(shape);

                        // Referansı UserSurface olarak kullanma
                        UserSurface userSurface = (UserSurface)reference;

                        // Açıklama oluşturma
                        Annotation annotation = annotationFactory.CreateEvoluateText(userSurface, 0, 0, 0, true);

                        // Açıklama metnini ayarlama
                        annotation.set_Name(metric);

                        part.Update();
                    }
                }


Is reading the thread description or creating a annotation your problem? What error do you get?

@Shrotter both of them actually It can't creating it. I tried in catscript works fine in about creating annotation but not thread description.  In c# both of them not working maybe I missing something.

@Shrotter And also I didn't recieve any error looks like working but code is doing nothing and nothing happened in catia. When I arrive to home I will try it again.

What values do you get from HoleThreadDescription? Are all your holes threaded? (Maybe check with .ThreadingMode first)

@Shrotter yes, all of my holes all threaded. but for example one of them M16 other one M12 etc... I getting thread values names like m1 m2 m3 ... m20

And how about hole annotation coordinations any idea? I wanted annotation will next to hole but didn't figure it out. I will try your .ThreadingMode It giving me hope thank you. When I arrive to my home I will try it out. @Shrotter

For coordinates you may have a look onto the GetOrigin method of a hole
